# I18n-js - is there a way to check if a translation exists or not?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, translation, i18n-js

Is there a way to check if a translation exists or not with the library I18n-js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `lookup()`.

It returns `undefined` when the translation does not exist, so you can put it in your conditional.

For example:

```html
if(!I18n.lookup('translation_key')) {
  console.log('Translation does not exist');
}
else {
  console.log('Translation does exist. Congrats.');
}
```